# Modify @Published variable from another class that is not declared in | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to put the logic of all my `@Published` in a model class, however when I try to separate it, it doesn't update. I recreated a little example:

The code below works, it increases every time the button is clicked:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var myClass = MyClass()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            myClass.doStuff(numb: 1)
        }) {
            Text("People: \(myClass.people)")
        }
    }
}


class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people: Int = 0

    func doStuff(numb: Int) {
        people += numb
    }
}
```

However, once I split the logic and try to have my @Published in a separate class to have it more clean, it doesn't update, see below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myClass = MyClass()
    
    let modify = Modify()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            modify.doStuff(numb: 1)
        }) {
            Text("People: \(myClass.people)")
        }
    }
}

class Modify {
    var myClass = MyClass()
    
    func doStuff(numb: Int) {
        myClass.people += numb
    }
}


class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people: Int = 0
}
```

I think it's because there are two different instances in the view right? Anyway, how can I separate the @Publish correctly have it updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first form is absolutely fine! You may, though, consider your ContentView using a `@ObservedObject` instead a `@StateObject`.

Your second form is flawed, for several reasons:

1. don't move logic into a view
2. don't use class variables to keep "state".

The first statement is due to a sane design that keeps your models and views nicely separated.

The second statement is due to how SwiftUI works. If you need to have some "state" in your views, use `@State` where the value is a *struct*.

Using `@State` ensures, that it's value is bound to the actual life time of the "conceptual view", i.e. the thing we human perceive as *the* view. And this "conceptual view" (managed as some data object by SwiftUI) is *distinct* from the struct *View*, which is merely a means to describe how to create and modify this conceptual view - that is, struct view is rather a *function* that will be used to initially create the "conceptual view" and modify it. Once this is done, it gets destroyed, and gets recreated when the conceptual view needs to be modified. That also means, the life time of this struct is not bound to the life time of its "state". The state's life time is bound to the conceptual view, and thus has usually longer life time than the struct view, where the struct view can be created and destroyed several times.

Now, imagine what happens when you always execute `let modify = Modify()` whenever the (conceptual) view or its content view is modified and needs to be recalculated and rendered by creating a *struct view* and then - after it has been rendered - destroying it again.

Also, this "state" is considered *private* for the view, means it is considered an implementation detail for the view. If you want to exchange data from "outside" and "inside" use a `@ObservedObject` or a `Binding`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have 2 separate instances of `MyClass`:

> `@StateObject var myClass = MyClass()`

> `var myClass = MyClass()`

You are updating the `myClass` in `Modify`, which you aren't receiving updates from. A way to fix this is by having one instance of `MyClass`, passed into `Modify` during initialization:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var myClass: MyClass
    let modify: Modify

    init() {
        let temp = MyClass()
        _myClass = StateObject(wrappedValue: temp)
        modify = Modify(myClass: temp)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            modify.doStuff(numb: 1)
        }) {
            Text("People: \(myClass.people)")
        }
    }
}

class Modify {
    let myClass: MyClass

    init(myClass: MyClass) {
        self.myClass = myClass
    }

    func doStuff(numb: Int) {
        myClass.people += numb
    }
}
```

---

Another method is to have a `@Published` property in `Modify` to observe the changes of `MyClass`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var modify = Modify()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            modify.doStuff(numb: 1)
        }) {
            Text("People: \(modify.myClass.people)")
        }
    }
}

class Modify: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myClass = MyClass()
    private var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        anyCancellable = myClass.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] _ in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    func doStuff(numb: Int) {
        myClass.people += numb
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the point, there you are not creating two classes. Also those init there are very ugly, it could get messy later on

Comment: @Albert I think your original way was way better anyway. However, you are creating two instances. You are changing an instance which you are not observing the changes of.

Comment: So am I supposed to have all the @Published in the same ViewModel class? Isn't there a way to have them in another class to have more clean code?

Comment: @Albert Added a second method which you may prefer more

Comment: No with both of your answers you are doing the same thing as me lol, that doesn't answer the question :/

Comment: @Albert I thought the problem was that the button wasn't updating, after splitting up the code? In the end, you can only have one instance of `MyClass` and so these are the only possible ways to do this. If I am misunderstand something else, let me know

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach using a singleton. Works well for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myClass = MyClass.shared  // <--- here
    
    let modify = Modify()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            modify.doStuff(numb: 1)
        }) {
            Text("People: \(myClass.people)")
        }
    }
}

class Modify {
    var myClass = MyClass.shared   // <--- here
    
    func doStuff(numb: Int) {
        myClass.people += numb
    }
}


class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people: Int = 0
    static let shared = MyClass()    // <--- here
}
```

Comment: You would never use `let modify = Modify()` in a View. You may provide an API in MyClass (for example `send(event: Event`) which calls through the internals (Modify). class Modify does not need to be exposed to the View. Name MyClass -> ViewModel and Modify -> Model - then it should be clear ;)