# How can I update the @Published property of a class based on @Published property in another @ObservedObject in Swift?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

Let me give you a simplified example of my problem.

My application structure is,
View <- Viewmodel <- UserRepository <- UserStorageService

in the above view and view model are pretty self-explanatory. UserRespository is an `ObservableObject`, which works as a single data source for the view model.
UserStorageService is another ObervableObject which handles read/write data from `CoreData`.

With this approach I can easily change the method I fetch data in my application. as an example if I want to fetch data from an api I have to replace the StorageService with an APIService.

Let me show you my sample code,
`UserStorageService.swift`

```
class UserStorageService: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    private let userController: NSFetchedResultsController<User>
    private let dataController: DataController
    
    init(controller: DataController) {
        dataController = controller
        let fetchRequest = User.fetchRequest()
        userController = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: dataController.container.viewContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil
        )
        
        super.init()
        
        userController.delegate = self
    }
    
    func add(data: User) throws {
        // Add implementation
    }
    
    func fetch() throws {
        try userController.performFetch()
        users = userController.fetchedObjects ?? []
    }
    
}


extension UserStorageService: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        
        guard let users = userController.fetchedObjects else {
            return
        }
        self.users = users
    }
}
```

This class will fetch data from `CoreData` and keeps the `users` property updated when it changes.

On my `UserRepository.swift` class I have created a @StateObject instance of `UserStorageService` and also a `@Published` property `users` which will be used in my view model as a source of truth for users.

```
class UserRepository: RepositoryProtocol, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    @StateObject var userStorageService: UserStorageService
    
    init(dataController: DataController) {
        let storageService = UserStorageService(controller: dataController)
        _userStorageService = StateObject(wrappedValue: storageService)
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        try? userStorageService.fetch()
        users = userStorageService.users
    }
    
    func add(data: User) throws {
        try? userStorageService.add(data: data)
    }
}
```

My question is, whenever the storage changes it updates the users in `UserStorageService` class. When that happens, how do I update the `users` property in my `UserRepository` class which will eventually update the view model and updates the UI.

I am newbie, any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify @Published variable from another class that is not declared in | SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675389/modify-published-variable-from-another-class-that-is-not-declared-in-swiftui)

Comment: Why can you not just use a binding to users in `UserStorageService`?  I maybe oversimplifying it.

Comment: The first linked answer should give you what you need. I think it's also worth pointing out that using a `@StateObject` property wrapper *inside* an `ObservableObject` doesn't do anything -- that's for use inside `View`s. It might lead to a false sense that you're going to get some updates automatically, which as you've experienced, is not the case.

Comment: @Yrb I went through the thread. For my understanding what it says is that not to use `class` to track state in a view. It was really helpful to understand how SwiftUI view works.
But I am not quite sure how that applies to my question here.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Singleton pattern. Create one in your main class and use **users** variable to update it inside another class

> `static var singleton: UserStorageService = UserStorageService()`

After declaration you can use it in **UserRepository**

> `@Published var users: [User] = UserStorageService.singleton.users`

2. Also , this can be achieved with **Combine** framework, which implements Observer Design Pattern, where you have one Publisher and Subscribers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't want to use a singleton. I will have multiple storage service classes and I will end up using singleton in all the places. Don't feel like a good architecture.

Comment: In this case the best solution is **Observer Design Pattern**, do you know how to implement it? You have to use **Combine framework**

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a published UserStorageService in your UserRepository then subscribe to it in the init() to pass any changes along to your users array:

```swift
@Published var userStorageService = UserStorageService()

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init() {
    userStorageService.$users
        .assign(to: \.users, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

This requires you to import the Combine framework.